# UIImageView and NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using XML to extract images. I've accomplished to parse the XML and according to the log files there should be nothing wrong with the parsing. How do I show those images? In the XML, they are stored as plain URLs with the tag `image`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the url from the image tag through parsing and then populate it in a tableview or some other view.

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourImagename.jpg"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * urlImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData]; 
myImageView.urlImage = image;
```

Comment: Even though this answer certainly is correct, still I would like to add and emphasize that this solution is working synchronously and will block your app while downloading the image data.

Comment: I want to load multiple images